# Probability beamer theme

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to present my thesis in stochastic area  with some beautiful Beamer theme I found useful website  http://latex.simon04.net/.
[image]
But as my thesis is in stochastic (probability) I search if there are any themes which contain style or background like this 
[image]
[image]
Could someone indicate me of any probability theme if it exists

Comment: Are you asking if there are any themes with dices in the background? If yes, why don't you just put the image you found in the background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you need this level of customization, it is unlikely that you find themes which suit perfectly all you need, and it is time for you to do the "dirty work" yourself.

Adding a background image to a beamer presentation is possible using the `background canvas` template.

A very basic MWE (I didn't change the color of anything to make the text readable, nor did I try to tweak the alignment).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{HetqF}}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{And a frame}
  With some text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The images you provided don't make a good fit for a background, they don't have a high-enough resolution, and they are too colorful for the text to be readable. But that's no longer a latex problem.

Edit: As mentioned by [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow) in a comment, the readability issue can be tackled with Latex features, using `tikz` to change the opacity of the included picture.

His code snippet also shows how one can change the placement of the picture, by aligning it to the right.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\vbox to\paperheight{\vfil\hbox to\paperwidth{\hfil\tikz\node[opacity=0.15]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{HetqF}};‌​}\vfil}}
% 0.0625 wasn't enough for the picture to be easily visible on my screen
```

[image]

If you want to have a different image on each slide, you have a few solutions.

The first one is to manually define the background at each slide (thanks to [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow) for this solution).

For this, you put in the preamble:

```
\newenvironment{background}[1]{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics{#1}}}{}
```

and you call it using

```
\begin{background}{image1}
  \begin{frame}
    ...
  \end{frame}
\end{background}
```

Another option, if you want to cycle amongst a few images only, is to use the beamer template system. That is, you define different templates for the background in the preamble:

```
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{background1}{\includegraphics{image1}}
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{background1}{\includegraphics{image1}}
```

and then you can use them in the document

```
\setbeamertemplate{backgroundcanvas}[background1] % Square brackets, not braces
\begin{frame}
  ...
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Something like `\vbox to\paperheight{\vfil\hbox to\paperwidth{\hfil\tikz\node[opacity=0.0625]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{HetqF}};}\vfil}` makes the text readable (also it aligns the image right).

Comment: @MarkWibrow Thank you very much, I editted the post to include it.

Comment: wow Thanks so much i like that way it's wonderful thanks again

Comment: Can we make different background for each frame

Comment: @Educ just put `TeX` group around each frame including the `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}`. You could then tie it all up in a custom `background` environment to make things a bit cleaner, for example `\newenvironment{background}[1]{\includegraphics{#1}}{}` (for space I've missed out `\vbox` and `\tikz` stuff) so you could say `\begin{background}{HetqF}\begin{frame}...\end{frame}\end{background}`.

Comment: Actually, the environment bit wrong. It should say `\newenvironment{background}[1]{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics{#1}}}{}`

Comment: @MarkWibrow : Thank you again. Added it to the answer, together with another solution using named templates.

Comment: Thanks Mr Mark Wibrow  but doesn't work where is tikz

Comment: @Educ you'd need `\usepackage{tikz}` in your preamble. `TikZ` should be in any standard distribution, but if you don't need it for anything else and don't want to load it just for background images then `\pgfpicture\pgfsetfillopacity{0.0625}\pgftext{\includegraphics{#1}}\endpgfpicture` will achieve the same thing.

Comment: the code \newenvironment{background}[1]{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics{#1}}}{}        give images don't make a good fit for a background that why we have to use tikz with that code but i can't give me the all detaills please